# Hammer.js - Rotation in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10, hammer.js

I'm having some trouble with the hammer.js-touch-framework, to be more precise, the rotation-trigger. My code is pretty minimalistic, as you can see in this jsfiddle (I'm using jquery.hammer.js from the official hammer.js-website):

http://jsfiddle.net/kgEFs/

My main problem is, that `rotation` and `pinch` both are not triggered, only tap gets fired. 
I know, other browsers might be better for web-development, but I'm interested in how I can make my object rotate, even in Internet Explorer. 
Tapping on the `<div>` with MSIE 10 triggers the tapping event and even could rotate the object, if there was a value (you can check by simply changing `e.rotation` to `10`). I already got the rotation-event once, but I can't reproduce how I achieved it.

Any ideas?